# Flow Rate in a tube with zero roughness

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, flow

[image: Diagram of the setup]

Assume the following setup. Given the Diameter of the pipe, difference in elevation (z1 - z2),  pipe length, what would be the theoretical way of determining the flow rate (Q) within tube? Assume roughness to be equal to zero. Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: Welcome to Physics.SE! Please note that [homework-like problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) that just ask for the solution to a given problem are off-topic here.

Comment: Did Bernoulli's theorem cross your mind?